# If a condition is met on one column but duplicates exist in a separate column... mark all - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wasn't entirely sure how to word this but I'll do my best to explain the results I need.

What I need to know using a case statement (or anything that is suggested) is if there's a heading code that is restricted and the CTN is the same (duplicated) across multiple heading codes... case statement needs to return 'Restricted from Call Recording' for all instances where the CTN is the same.

My Query:

```
select 
unique ae.ctn, 
ae.heading_code,
case
when ae.heading_code in ('8003520') then 'Restricted from Call Recording'
end as status
from advertiser_extract ae
where ae.customer_id = '245433513'
and ae.tier in ('20','21','22','25','26','27','30','40','50','60','100','800');
```

The results generated:

```
 ctn           | heading_code | status
---------------+--------------+-------------------------------
(888) 350-5030 | 8004777      | 
(612) 315-1320 | 8015370      |
(888) 350-5030 | 8015370      |
(888) 350-5030 | 8003520      | Restricted from Call Recording
(612) 315-1320 | 8008781      | 
(888) 350-5030 | 8000121      | 
(612) 315-1310 | 8000121      | 
(612) 315-1910 | 8003520      | Restricted from Call Recording
(612) 315-1910 | 8004777      | 
(888) 350-5030 | 8008781      |
```

However, what I need is something like this:

```
 ctn           | heading_code | status
---------------+--------------+-------------------------------
(888) 350-5030 | 8004777      | Restricted from Call Recording
(612) 315-1320 | 8015370      |
(888) 350-5030 | 8015370      | Restricted from Call Recording
(888) 350-5030 | 8003520      | Restricted from Call Recording
(612) 315-1320 | 8008781      | 
(888) 350-5030 | 8000121      | Restricted from Call Recording
(612) 315-1310 | 8000121      | 
(612) 315-1910 | 8003520      | Restricted from Call Recording
(612) 315-1910 | 8004777      | Restricted from Call Recording
(888) 350-5030 | 8008781      | Restricted from Call Recording
```

This is basically telling me that although the heading code exists for two rows, the CTN tied to that heading code exists within multiple rows and should be restricted from call recording. In this example CTN: (888) 350-5030 & (612) 315-1910 has a heading code (8003520) that is restricted but these CTNs are associated to other heading codes and by default should be labeled.

Any ideas and examples using my query will help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `max()` analytic function:

```
select distinct ae.ctn, ae.heading_code,
       max(case when ae.heading_code in ('8003520') then 'Restricted from Call Recording'
           end) over (partition by ae.ctn) as status
from advertiser_extract ae
where ae.customer_id = '245433513' and
      ae.tier in ('20','21','22','25','26','27','30','40','50','60','100','800');
```

Note:  You should not use `select distinct` unless you really have to.

Comment: My hat is off to you sir. Thank you. This gave me the result I needed and worked across the board with all other customers I tested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should change your `case` expression to reflect that like

```
case
when ae.ctn = '(888) 350-5030' or ae.heading_code = '8003520' 
then 'Restricted from Call Recording' end as status
```

Comment: the problem is that the ctn number itself can change based on the customer id searched. So as a different user running the query, they would need to change ae.ctn = '(888) 350-5030' to a different CTN every time.